# Django - querying many FK models from parent

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Given the following pseudo code:

```
class A(models.Model)

class B(models.Model)
    a = models.FK(A)

class C(models.Model)
    b = models.FK(B)

class D(models.Model)
    b = models.FK(B)
```

If I have the PK of A, how may I retrieve all related instances of every child model? (B, C and D).

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: Well a problem is that an FK does not per se defines a parent-child relation. Imagine that `A` also has an FK to `B`, then there is a *cyclic* relation. This can result in infinite recursion/loops.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion only way is loop all.
Define some related name and you can try like like this. Pseudo pk of A = pk

```
class A(models.Model):

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.FK(A, related_name='related_B')

class C(models.Model):
    b = models.FK(B, related_name='related_C')

class D(models.Model):
    b = models.FK(B, related_name='related_D')


a = A.objects.get(pk=pk)
results = []
results.append(a.related_B.all())
for item in a.related_B.all():
    results.append(item.related_C.all())
    results.append(item.related_D.all())
```

and results now have all related instances of every child model of A.
Hoop this help